# Room temperature monitor software

Tags: temperature

There are lots of tools to see your CPU etc temperature, but I'm looking for a tool to monitor your room temperature.
I don't know if my PC have the hardware to do this, but maybe it's build in?

Thanks

Comment: Great idea. I do however not think that an accurate solution does exist. The devices in a PC would always be somewhat heated by themselves.

Comment: "Room temperature", as in ambient temperature outside the case? If so, additional hardware is required for data collection - a pure software method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a [room temperatur scan software](http://www.freeware-download.com/downloaddetails/18286.html). All you need is a probe and a usb device.